# expand search bar onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, I´m trying to do a basic jQuery example that expands a search bar on mouse click, and I dont understand why nothing is happening with my code. I have a basic jQuery to show the input when I click in my (button class="expand"), but when I click in this button the input that is setting in css with display:none dont appears.

**My basic jQuery script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$('.expand').click(function() {
$('#test').show(500);
```

});

**My html:**

```
 <nav id="menu">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>      
            <li id="sb-search" style="float:right; list-style:none; height:20px;">
            <div id="pesquisar-container">
            <span id="pesquisar" class="form-container cf">
            <form  name="form1" >
                <input id="test" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar..." required="required" onfocus="if(this.placeholder == 'Search...') {this.placeholder=''}" onblur="if(this.placeholder == ''){this.placeholder ='Search...'}" />
                <button class="expand" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
            </span> 
           </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
    </nav>
```

**My css:**

```
     .form-container input {
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:'bariol_lightlight';
    border: 0;
    background: #f3f3f3; /*#fcfcfc se o fundo for branco, ver as diferenças */
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;  
    margin-top: 9px;  
    color:#000;  
    display:none;
}

    .form-container button {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 25px;
        width: 35px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #363f48;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;      
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        margin-top:9px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(function() {...});`

```
$(function() {
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $('#test').show(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, exactly that! And also thank you for the documentation link, It was very good to understand my error.

Answer (score 0):

There can be the couple of reasons.
1. Put your click listeners on document ready 
2. Better assign some id to button. let's say its btnSubmit.
3. following methods can be used to show or hide the elements.

```
$(selector).hide(speed,callback);
$(selector).show(speed,callback);
```

or its better to use toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $("#test").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Hope this will help.